# WooCommerce Booking - Retrieving specific data on Thank You page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On the Thank You page (Order Received page) I would like to retrieve specific data with a function:

```
Booking ID (_booking_id);
Booking Date (_start_date);
Booking Time;
Booking Persons (_persons);
```

This should replace the data Woocommerce Bookings outputs by default. On the Cart page I got this working, but on the Thank You page I can't seem to get it to work.

The function should begin with (I think):

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order->id );
```

How can I retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the booking data this way:

```
global $wpdb;

$booking_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = '_booking_order_item_id' AND meta_value = %d;", $item_id ) );

$wcBooking = new WC_Booking($booking_id);

$start = $wcBooking->get_start_date();
$end= $wcBooking->get_end_date();
$resource = $wcBooking->get_resource();
$option = $resource->post_title;

echo '<br/><small>From: '.$start.' </small>';
echo '<br/><small>To:  '.$end.' </small>';
echo '<br/><small>Option:  '.$option.' </small>';
```

Comment: The data is showing now, but it's not being updated. On every booking the same data is being displayed. And it's not the data from the most recent booking. Is there a way to get the correct data?      


Also I'd like to know how to get the data form '_persons'. It's being displayed as an array:     


 `Array
(
    [0] => 12
)`  


Thanks!